# How to include file from another file in the same directory of the same project?

Tags: rust

I started a new project in rust (it's my first project in rust, but my first programming language). I added a few functions, types and unit test in `main.rs`. Then I wanted to move it in two new files `foo.rs` and `bar.rs`.

**How do I import/include/use `bar.rs` from `foo.rs`?**

---

I already read:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html
- [How do I do a basic import/include of a function from one module to another in Rust 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224947/how-do-i-do-a-basic-import-include-of-a-function-from-one-module-to-another-in-r)
- [Split a module across several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596920/split-a-module-across-several-files)
- [How to include module from another file from the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388861/how-to-include-module-from-another-file-from-the-same-project)
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/mod.html

Neither have the following structure

```
src/
|-- main.rs
|-- foo.rs
|-- bar.rs
```

Where `foo.rs` is trying to use the content of `bar.rs`.

---

If I try to use a type `Bar` declared in `bar.rs` directly from `foo.rs`, I get:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `Bar`
  --> src/foo.rs
```

---

If I add `mod bar` at the beginning of `foo.rs` isn't any better:

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `bar`
 --> src/foo.rs
  |
1 | mod bar;
  |     ^^^
  |
  = help: name the file either foo/bar.rs or foo/bar/mod.rs inside the directory "src"
```

---

And finally (but I wasn't expecting this one to work), with `use bar;` in `foo.rs`:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `bar`
 --> src/foo.rs
  |
1 | use bar;
  |     ^^^ no `grammar` external crate
```

Comment: *In a mainish module (main.rs, lib.rs, or subdir/mod.rs), you need to write `mod a;` for all other modules that you want to use in your whole project (or in the subdir). In any other module, you need to write `use a;` or `use a::foo;`* You need **both** `mod bar;` **and** `use bar;` (actually `crate::bar` here)

Comment: See also [How do I import from a sibling module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677258/how-do-i-import-from-a-sibling-module)

Comment: Oh, thanks. Why didn't you create a "real" answer so I could have selected it to flag this question as answered?

Comment: I was on mobile and didn't have the time to dedicate to a good answer. Also, I was pretty sure this had already been answered here, and I prefer to link questions together rather than write new answers. I found [How to include files from same directory in a module using Cargo/Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46829539/3650362) and [Why can't I import module from different file in same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55868434/3650362) (which was marked as a duplicate of one of the ones you linked, but also has an answer of its own).

Answer (score 1):

I answered a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76659218/1576548

There's 2 different problems at hand -- there's how to import code from related modules (e.g. a `helpers.rs`) into your `main.rs`, but the procedure for doing that is different than importing code from other *NON-MAIN* modules into other *NON-MAIN* modules. The example I gave in the aforementioned question uses `a.rs`, `b.rs`, and `main.rs` all in the same directory, where you want to import functions between `a.rs` and `b.rs`.